# Best approach to track Amount field on Invoice table when InvoiceItem items change?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm building an app where I need to store invoices from customers so we can track who has paid and who has not, and if not, see how much they owe in total. Right now my schema looks something like this:

```
Customer
 - Id
 - Name

Invoice
 - Id
 - CreatedOn
 - PaidOn
 - CustomerId

InvoiceItem
 - Id
 - Amount
 - InvoiceId
```

Normally I'd fetch all the data using Entity Framework and calculate everything in my C# service, (or even do the calculation on SQL Server) something like so:

```
var amountOwed = Invoice.Where(i => i.CustomerId == customer.Id)
                        .SelectMany(i => i.InvoiceItems)
                        .Select(ii => ii.Amount)
                        .Sum()
```

But calculating everything every time I need to generate a report doesn't feel like the right approach this time, because down the line I'll have to generate reports that should calculate what all the customers owe (sometimes go even higher on the hierarchy).

For this scenario I was thinking of adding an `Amount` field on my `Invoice` table and possibly an `AmountOwed` on my `Customer` table which will be updated or populated via the `InvoiceService` whenever I insert/update/delete an `InvoiceItem`. This should be safe enough and make the report querying much faster.

But I've also been searching some on this subject and another recommended approach is using triggers on my database. I like this method best because even if I were to directly modify a value using SQL and not the app services, the other tables would automatically update.

My question is:

How do I add a trigger to update all the parent tables whenever an InvoiceItem is changed?

And from your experience, is this the best (safer, less error-prone) solution to this problem, or am I missing something?

Comment: why would you store redundant information ? It wont make your queries that much faster but sure can lead to problems if they are not correctly maintained. If you really want to do this a trigger is the safest but slowest way to do it. All performance you think you gain will be lost and maybe even more by this system

Comment: There is no 100% safe way to do this. You can put a trigger on `InvoiceItem` that will update `Customer` and `Invoice` but it will not stop anyone on modifiying the values in `Customer` and `Invoice`

Comment: @GuidoG Why would it be redundant information? Isn't there a higher overhead if I load say 1M invoice items to calculate Invoice totals every time I need too? Instead of storing those  totals in the invoice tables and just use those?

As for modifying the customer and invoice tables I think I could just add a user with permissions limited to InvoiceItem table.

Comment: what happens everytime you update a row in `InvoiceItem` table ? Then you have to find and update the rows in the other 2 tables at that time. When they hold millions of records than this will slow you down at that time. that is my point

Comment: If you have to do it, triggers is your only option. I know lots of people tell you to avoid it, but its the only system that 100% guarantees the business logic will be executed and maintained

Comment: @GuidoG Oh, I see your point now. Yeah I figured the overhead would be added to the change operations, just didn't take into account that it would outweigh the benefits gained on the report generation. Thanks.

Comment: I am not saying that it would, but on large tables it very well could. So do some tests on performance before you go for such a system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many examples of triggers that you can find on the web. Many are poorly written unfortunately. And for future reference, post DDL for your tables, not some abbreviated list. No one should need to ask about the constraints and relationships you have (or should have) defined.

To start, how would you write a query to calculate the total amount at the invoice level? Presumably you know the tsql to do that. So write it, test it, verify it. Then add your amount column to the invoice table. Now how would you write an update statement to set that new amount column to the sum of the associated item rows? Again - write it, test it, verify it. At this point you have all the code you need to implement your trigger.

Since this process involves changes to the item table, you will need to write triggers to handle all three types of dml statements - insert, update, and delete. Write a trigger for each to simplify your learning and debugging. Triggers have access to special tables - go learn about them. And go learn about the false assumption that a trigger works with a single row - it doesn't. Triggers must be written to work correctly if 0 (yes, zero), 1, or many rows are affected.

In an insert statement, the inserted table will hold all the rows inserted by the statement that caused the trigger to execute. So you merely sum the values (using the appropriate grouping logic) and update the appropriate rows in the invoice table. Having written the update statement mentioned in the previous paragraphs, this should be a relatively simple change to that query. But since you can insert a new row for an old invoice, you must remember to add the summed amount to the value already stored in the invoice table. This should be enough direction for you to start.

And to answer your second question - the safest and easiest way is to calculate the value every time. I fear you are trying to solve a problem that you do not have and that you may never have. Generally speaking, no one cares about invoices that are of "significant" age. You might care about unpaid invoices for a period of time, but eventually you write these things off (especially if the amounts are not significant). Another relatively easy approach is to create an indexed view to calculate and materialize the total amount. But remember - nothing is free. An indexed view must be maintained and it will add extra processing for DML statements affecting the item table. Indexed views do have limitations - which are documented.

And one last comment. I would strongly hesitate to maintain a total amount at any level higher than invoice. Above that level one frequently wants to filter the results in any ways - date, location, type, customer, etc. At this level you are approaching data warehouse functionality which is not appropriate for a OLTP system.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I think I'll try the trigger approach and limit it only to compute the amount col in the Invoice table, and everything else I'll calculate on the fly. "I fear you are trying to solve a problem that you do not have and that you may never have."  -- I also fear I do this more often than I should do. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First of all never use triggers for business logic. Triggers are tricky and easily forgettable. It will be hard to maintain such application.

For most cases you can easily populate your reporting data via entity framework or SQL query. But if it requires lots of joins then you need to consider using staging tables. Because reporting requires data denormalization. To populate staging tables you can use SQL jobs or other schedule mechanism (Azure Scheduler maybe). This way you won't need to work with lots of join and your reports will populate faster.

Comment: Sure, this seems like a better solution but I think it's an overkill for my application. As I'm not working on a large scale ERP, rather an app with a lot of data in a few tables where reports are generated frequently. So I'm just looking for simpler methods to cut some joins and a few seconds of calculating time.